# python "re" package, strange phenomenon with "raw" string

Tags: python, regex

I am seeing the following phenomenon, couldn't seem to figure it out, and didn't find anything with some search through archives:

if I type in:

```
>>> if re.search(r'\n',r'this\nis\nit'):<br>
...     print 'found it!'<br>
... else:<br>
...     print "didn't find it"<br>
...
```

I will get:

```
didn't find it!
```

However, if I type in:

```
>>> if re.search(r'\\n',r'this\nis\nit'):<br>
...     print 'found it!'<br>
... else:<br>
...     print "didn't find it"<br>
...
```

Then I will get:

```
found it!
```

(The first one only has one backslash on the r'\n' whereas the second one has two backslashes in a row on the r'\\n' ... even this interpreter is removing one of them.)
I can guess what is going on, but I don't understand the official mechanism as to why this is happening:  in the first case, I need to escape two things:  both the regular expression and the special strings.  "Raw" lets me escape the special strings, but not the regular expression.
But there will never be a regular expression in the second string, since it is the string being matched.  So there is only a need to escape once. 
However, something doesn't seem consistent to me:  how am I supposed to ensure that the characters *REALLY ARE* taken literally in the first case?  Can I type rr'' ?  Or do I have to ensure that I escape things twice?
On a similar vein, how do I ensure that a variable is taken literally (or that it is *NOT* taken literally)?  E.g., what if I had a variable tmp = 'this\nis\nmy\nhome', and I really wanted to find the literal combination of a slash and an 'n', instead of a newline?
Thanks!
Mike

Comment: "On a similar vein, how do I ensure that a variable is taken literally (or that it is NOT taken literally)? E.g., what if I had a variable tmp = 'this\nis\nmy\nhome', and I really wanted to find the literal combination of a slash and an 'n', instead of a newline?" Then you would search for `r'\\\\n'`, I suppose.

Comment: `re.search(r'\\\n',r'this\nis\nit')` should not match btw, `re.search(r'\\n',r'this\nis\nit')` should.

Comment: @junjanes I picked up on that too. It appears someone edited the question and accidentally added a third slash. I have reverted it. Now it makes sense.

Comment: I had to add the third \ because stackoverflow was removing one of the \'s when I first submitted it... hence the edit.  I knew that no matter how I submitted it, it would be confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
re.search(r'\n', r'this\nis\nit')
```

As you said, "there will never be a regular expression in the second string." So we need to look at these strings differently: the first string is a regex, the second just a string. Usually your second string will not be raw, so any backslashes are Python-escapes, not regex-escapes.

So the first string consists of a literal "\" and an "n". This is interpreted by the regex parser as a newline ([docs](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html): "Most of the standard escapes supported by Python string literals are also accepted by the regular expression parser"). So your regex will be searching for a newline character.

Your second string consists of the string "this" followed by a literal "\" and an "n". So this string does not contain an actual newline character. Your regex will not match.

As for your second regex:

```
re.search(r'\\n', r'this\nis\nit')
```

This version matches because your regex contains three characters: a literal "\", another literal "\" and an "n". The regex parser interprets the two slashes as a single "\" character, followed by an "n". So your regex will be searching for a "\" followed by an "n", which is found within the string. But that isn't very helpful, since it has nothing to do with newlines.

Most likely what you want is to drop the `r` from the second string, thus treating it as a normal Python string.

```
re.search(r'\n', 'this\nis\nit')
```

In this case, your regex (as before) is searching for a newline character. And, it finds it, because the second string contains the word "this" followed by a newline.

Comment: Thanks for the clarity!  I did understand what was happening, but I don't understand the particular cases.  To be more specific:  I want to ensure that there are no "weird characters" being captured in my code.  Therefore, I want to make sure there are no newlines, tabs, etc. in the string to be checked (the 2nd string).  So in this case, let's say the string I'm testing is "temp", how would I test the string?  E.g., could I do:  `if re.search(r'\n',temp)` to test for a newline in temp?  What if temp has a "\n" in it, but as a literal "\" + "n"... I don't understany how Python differentiates.

Comment: Well if `temp` is a string variable, then that will be fine. The escaping is only relevant for *string literals* -- that is, actual quoted representations of strings in the source code. If you have a variable with a string in it, then there's no escaping. There's just newline characters, backslash characters and 'n' characters. If `temp` has a newline in it (ASCII 10), then your regex will find it. If `temp` has a backslash (ASCII 92) then an 'n' (ASCII 110), then your regex will not find a newline. Use `map(ord, temp)` to see the ASCII values in `temp`, which should make it clear.

Comment: @mguica Thanks so much!  Your comment above was super-detailed & clear, which is what I'd needed.  :)

Answer (score 2):

Escaping special sequences in string literals is one thing, escaping regular expression special characters is another. The row string modifier only effects the former.

Technically, `re.search` accepts two strings and passes the first to the regex builder with `re.compile`. The compiled regex object is used to search patterns inside simple strings. The second string is never compiled and thus it is not subject to regex special character rules.

If the regex builder receives a `\n` after the string literal is processed, it converts this sequence to a newline character. You also have to escape it if you need the match the sequence instead.

All rationale behind this is that regular expressions are not part of the language syntax. They are rather handled within the standard library inside the `re` module with common building blocks of the language.

The `re.compile` function uses special characters and escaping rules compatible with most commonly used regex implementations. However, the Python interpreter is not aware of the whole regular expression concept and it does not know whether a string literal will be compiled into a regex object or not. As a result, Python can't provide any kind syntax simplification such as the ones you suggested.

Comment: `re.compile` first sees `r'\\n'` as `'\\\\n'`, then the regex language kicks in and removes the *escaped \\*. So the regex looks for a literal `\\n` when the text is `'this\\nis\\nit` -- that's why it matches.

Comment: Only two slashes are passed to the regex compiler. Which then replaces them with one. Also I don't think `r'\\n'` is ever converted to `'\\\\n'`. The interpreter can immediately build an internal three-character sequence in memory when it is parsing the raw string literal. The object of the `r` modifier is to bypass any conversion in this process. However, this is still unknown to the regex builder which only works with representations in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Regexes have their own meaning for literal backslashes, as character classes like `\d`. If you actually want a literal backslash character, you will in fact need to double-escape it. It's really not supposed to be parallel since you're comparing a regex to a string.

Raw strings are just a convenience, and it would be way overkill to have double-raw strings.